# Why the message "raspberrypi dhclient: send_packet: Network is unreachable"?

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, raspbian-jessie, debian, dhcp

I am having a raspberry pi jessie OS. I configured it as ethernet to ethernet router. eth0 is connected to a modem and eth1 is actually a usb to eth converter. Rpi get internet through the eth0 interface and eth1 is connected to ubiquity for providing wifi hotspot. All are working well for a day and suddenly something is happened to the Rpi. I got the following messages in the syslog.

```
Sep  7 06:24:09 raspberrypi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67
Sep  7 06:24:09 raspberrypi dhclient: send_packet: Network is unreachable
Sep  7 06:24:09 raspberrypi dhclient: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
Sep  7 06:24:10 raspberrypi dhclient: dhclient.c:2243: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
```

After 8 hours, this message is changed to following

```
Sep  7 14:34:38 raspberrypi dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
Sep  7 14:34:38 raspberrypi dhclient: send_packet: No such device
Sep  7 14:34:38 raspberrypi dhclient: dhclient.c:1966: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over eth0 interface.
```

and then to

```
Sep  7 14:35:32 raspberrypi dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Sep  7 14:35:32 raspberrypi dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

So I have rebooted the machine. After reboot, it again became to working condition. 
Can anyone help me to understand what is going on?

This is the full log error before the above-said lines. Can you please look at the log. I was unable to understand it.

```
Sep  6 17:41:15 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) 68:c6:3a:94:d9:cd
Sep  6 17:41:15 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 192.168.42.40 68:c6:3a:94:d9:cd
Sep  6 17:41:15 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 192.168.42.40 68:c6:3a:94:d9:cd
Sep  6 17:41:15 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPACK(eth1) 192.168.42.40 68:c6:3a:94:d9:cd ESP_94D9CD
Sep  6 17:42:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPACK(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94 ESP_65E594
Sep  6 17:42:15 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:15 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Fri Sep  6 17:43:45 2019 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Sep  6 17:42:15 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:15 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:15 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPACK(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94 ESP_65E594
Sep  6 17:42:23 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:23 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:23 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:23 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPACK(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94 ESP_65E594
Sep  6 17:44:11 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:44:11 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:44:11 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Fri Sep  6 17:45:41 2019 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Sep  6 17:44:11 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:44:11 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPACK(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94 ESP_65E594
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Fri Sep  6 17:48:27 2019 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi dhclient: receive_packet failed on eth0: Network is down
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383021] usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383056] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383071] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383596] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383755] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address 2600:1012:b06e:a861:ba27:ebff:fe06:b162.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.2.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1012:b06e:a861:ba27:ebff:fe06:b162 on eth0.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.2 on eth0.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing workstation service for eth0.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.443570] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.443870] r8152 1-1.3:1.0 eth1: Stop submitting intr, status -108
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Interface eth1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv6 with address fe80::7288:6bff:fe82:1e8b.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Interface eth1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 192.168.42.1.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::7288:6bff:fe82:1e8b on eth1.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.42.1 on eth1.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing workstation service for eth1.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping ifup for eth1...
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi ifdown[9926]: Device "eth1" does not exist.
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.933064] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001901
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi ifdown[9926]: Cannot find device "eth1"
Sep  6 17:46:58 raspberrypi kernel: [232155.052939] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001901
Sep  6 17:46:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped ifup for eth1.
Sep  6 17:46:58 raspberrypi kernel: [232155.322923] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:46:58 raspberrypi kernel: [232155.592900] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:46:58 raspberrypi kernel: [232155.862896] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi kernel: [232156.132902] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi kernel: [232156.132949] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: Deleting interface #9 eth0, 2600:1012:b06e:a861:ba27:ebff:fe06:b162#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=81, dropped=0, active_time=30873 secs
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: 2600:1f16:7a3:8a22:a922:8e9c:be3:992a interface 2600:1012:b06e:a861:ba27:ebff:fe06:b162 -> (none)
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: Deleting interface #8 eth1, fe80::7288:6bff:fe82:1e8b#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=232141 secs
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: Deleting interface #6 eth0, fe80::ba27:ebff:fe06:b162#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=232143 secs
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: Deleting interface #4 eth1, 192.168.42.1#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=232143 secs
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: Deleting interface #3 eth0, 192.168.1.2#123, interface stats: received=951, sent=966, dropped=0, active_time=232143 secs
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: 107.155.79.108 interface 192.168.1.2 -> (none)
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: 108.61.73.243 interface 192.168.1.2 -> (none)
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: 23.131.160.7 interface 192.168.1.2 -> (none)
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi ntpd[693]: peers refreshed
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi kernel: [232156.252895] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi kernel: [232156.522892] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:46:59 raspberrypi kernel: [232156.792897] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:00 raspberrypi kernel: [232157.062887] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:00 raspberrypi kernel: [232157.332903] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Sep  6 17:47:00 raspberrypi kernel: [232157.332951] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:00 raspberrypi kernel: [232157.452882] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:00 raspberrypi kernel: [232157.722885] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:00 raspberrypi kernel: [232157.992890] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:01 raspberrypi kernel: [232158.262894] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:01 raspberrypi kernel: [232158.532886] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Sep  6 17:47:01 raspberrypi kernel: [232158.532932] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:01 raspberrypi kernel: [232158.652882] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:01 raspberrypi kernel: [232158.922886] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:02 raspberrypi kernel: [232159.192881] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:02 raspberrypi kernel: [232159.462889] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Sep  6 17:47:02 raspberrypi kernel: [232159.732890] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Sep  6 17:47:02 raspberrypi kernel: [232159.732925] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: Something has broken the network connection. The changed message after 8 hours is only a following error because the DHCP lease has expired and the RENEW fails because of the broken connection. But I can't help much more because I haven't used Jessie since years. It's old-old stable and you may consider to upgrade to up to date Buster.

Comment: @Ingo I have edited the question. Can you please look at the log?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a complete answer but you asked to look at the log. Due to formating issues it can only be done in an answer. But it may help you anyway.

```
Sep  6 17:42:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94
Sep  6 17:42:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[656]: DHCPACK(eth1) 192.168.42.93 5c:cf:7f:65:e5:94 ESP_65E594
```

There is a DHCP server `dnsmasq` running on the RasPi that serves ip addresses to interface **eth1** on subnet 192.168.42.0/24 (bitmask guessed). The DHCPREQESTs are successful (DHCPACK from device ESP_65E594) and devices on that subnet get an ip address. This implies that there **must not** run a second DHCP server on the wifi hotspot connected to **eth1** and its access point is bridged with the wired connection.

```
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.2 on eth0.
```

Interface **eth0** has ip address 192.168.1.2 to connect to the internet modem. I guess it is a static ip address. So we have two subnets 192.168.42.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 (bitmasks guessed) and we have to use routing to get access to the internet from the wifi hotspot. Routing must be enabled. Check with:

```
rpi ~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

This must return `1`. Now we come to the critical part:

```
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi dhclient: receive_packet failed on eth0: Network is down
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383021] usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383056] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383071] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383596] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.383755] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
--- snip ---
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.443570] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
Sep  6 17:46:57 raspberrypi kernel: [232154.443870] r8152 1-1.3:1.0 eth1: Stop submitting intr, status -108
```

As you can see the **kernel** is disabling the internal USB hub on the Raspberry Pi. All other messages are following errors of the disabled USB hub. The problem is that the built-in wired port is also connected to the internal USB hub so both interfaces **eth0** and **eth1** (USB/ethernet dongle) will fail. The reason why the **kernel** is doing this cannot be seen in the log. I would focus on the USB hub why it fails. First try to run the RasPi with only one ethernet cable connected to check what connection may give problems.